# names.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a deck of cards but getting the error in title when i run `deckOfCards`.

```
function deckOfCards() {
    const names = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'];
    const suits = ['Hearts','Diamonds','Spades','Clubs'];
    var deck = new Array(); 

    function card(name, suits) {
        this.name = name;
        this.suits = suits;
    }

    function createDeck() {
        suits.forEach(function (names) {
            names.forEach(function (type) {
                deck.push(new card(type, weight));
            });
        });
    }

    createDeck();
}
```

Comment: You are using the argument `names` (which is a string) not the global variable `names` (the array).

Comment: Hope you have closed your 'deckOfCards()' function in your code.

Comment: There are lots of problem here. For instance, where is `weight` coming from?

Comment: Because of forEach pass in variabke on function each item hence you cant access your global names array

Comment: It's supposed to be `suits.forEach(function (weight) {` I'd recommend thinking a bit more about your variable names though. Switching back and forth, and using a plural name for a singular value, etc will confuse you and lead to errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, I think this is what you were going for. I changed deckOfCards to be an object. Then fixed the createDeck variable issues.

**Javascript**: [jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/z960psy6/)

```
var deckOfCards = {
    names : ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'],
    suits : ['Hearts','Diamonds','Spades','Clubs'],
     deck : []
}

function card(name, suits){
    this.name = name;
    this.suits = suits;
}

function createDeck(){
    deckOfCards.suits.forEach(function (suit) {
        deckOfCards.names.forEach(function (name) {
           deckOfCards.deck.push(new card(name, suit));
        });
    });
}

createDeck();
console.log(deckOfCards.deck);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve

```js
function createDeck() {
        suits.forEach(function (weight) {
            names.forEach(function (type) {
                deck.push(new card(type, weight));
            });
        });
    }
```

Changing the "names" argument to "weight" should fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for the reason for this error, then you should know how forEach works.
You are replacing the global variable 'names' with the individual values of suit when u do the forEach of suit.

```js
function createDeck() {
        suits.forEach(function (names) {
            console.log(names)
        });
    }
```

will log

Hearts
Diamonds
Spades
Clubs

So first iteration of suits will replace the value of names to 'Hearts'.
Hence Names = 'Hearts' now.
And you're trying to perform forEach of 'Hearts'.

Now coming to the solution,

```js
function createDeck() {
        suits.forEach(function (weight) {
            names.forEach(function (type) {
                deck.push(new card(type, weight));
            });
        });
    }
```